# How to prove this inequality originating from complex analysis

Tags: inequality

Let $F$ be a smooth complex valued function defined on $\left [a, b \right]$. $p \ge 1$.

I'm wondering whether such an inequality is correct:

$$\left|\left| F(a)\right| ^{p}-\left| F(b)\right|^{p}\right|\leq p\int_{a}^{b}\left| F(x)\right| ^{p-1}\left|F^\prime(x)\right|dx$$

If $p$ is a positive integer, the inequality is valid by Newton-Leibniz formula. While for other $p$, the same method couldn't be applied ($F^{p}$ doesn't seem to be a good function in integral). Can anyone help me? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F=u+iv \in C^1([a,b],\mathbb{C})$, hence $u,v \in C^1([a,b],\mathbb{R})$.
Fix $\varepsilon >0$ and set $g(t):=(u(t)^2+v(t)^2+\varepsilon)^{p/2}$.
Now
$$
g'(t)=\frac{p}{2}(u(t)^2+v(t)^2+\varepsilon)^{p/2-1}(2u(t)u'(t)+2v(t)v'(t)).
$$
By Cauchy Schwarz we get
$$
|g'(t)| \le p(u(t)^2+v(t)^2+\varepsilon)^{p/2-1}(u(t)^2+v(t)^2)^{1/2}(u'(t)^2+v'(t)^2)^{1/2}
$$
$$
\le p(u(t)^2+v(t)^2+\varepsilon)^{p/2-1}(u(t)^2+v(t)^2+ \varepsilon)^{1/2}(u'(t)^2+v'(t)^2)^{1/2}
$$
$$
=p(u(t)^2+v(t)^2+\varepsilon)^{(p-1)/2}(u'(t)^2+v'(t)^2)^{1/2}.
$$
Now $g(b)-g(a)=\int_a^b g'(t) dt$, hence
$$
|g(b)-g(a)| \le p  \int_a^b(u(t)^2+v(t)^2+\varepsilon)^{(p-1)/2}(u'(t)^2+v'(t)^2)^{1/2} dt.
$$
Now $\varepsilon \to 0 +$ yields
$$
||F(b)|^p-|F(a)|^p| \le  p  \int_a^b(u(t)^2+v(t)^2)^{(p-1)/2}(u'(t)^2+v'(t)^2)^{1/2} dt = p  \int_a^b |F(t)|^{p-1} |F'(t)| dt
$$
In case $p \ge 2$ this should work directly with $g(t):=(u(t)^2+v(t)^2)^{p/2}$.